# HTML5 call variables form other pages

Tags: javascript, html

So i'm trying to implement this javascript function into an html page, but i need to call other variables from other pages.

```
  function concatWord(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,z)
{   
    var General = "Please send"+a+"to"+b+"as"+c+"works in"+d+"at"+e+"with"+f+"in the house of"+g+"using the hashtag"+g+"Thanks";

        return General;
}
```

So the variables the function receive are in seven different pages (a and z are in the same page), does anyone know how to call them? Thank you.

Comment: You will need to pass the values using some kind of persistence: cookies, localStorage, sessions, querystring parameters, etc.

Comment: There's no native include function in JavaScript. There has to be a better way to do what you need to do that this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is an interpreted language, it only lives as long as the page does. To pass variables in-between pages, you need to use a database system to save them. If you are using HTML5, have a look at [Local Storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html), which allows you  to store persistent information across pages without involving a server.

Comment: Okay, i'll try using my DB. Thank you very much.